# Java: does Object class have a constructor?

Tags: java, constructor

Javadoc mentions that Object class has a public no-arg constructor. But Object's source code doesn't have any explicit constructor in it. So obviously the compiler has generated one for it. However, if I see the call stack trace when a constructor is about to return (as shown below), I do not see any call to `Object.<init>` in that trace.

So the question is, does Object class have a default constructor as the doc says? If yes, why do I not see it in the call stack trace?

```
public ConTest()
{
    new Throwable().printStackTrace();
}
```

Result:

```
java.lang.Throwable
    at ConTest.<init>(ConTest.java:8)
    at ConTest.main(ConTest.java:16)
```

Comment: hmm from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html
 All classes have at least one constructor. If a class does not
explicitly declare any, the Java compiler automatically provides a
 no-argument constructor, called the default constructor. This default the Object constructor if the class has no other parent.

Comment: Is it possible to accept more than one answer? Because I'd like to accept all 4 answers given below.

Comment: Strange, @shrini1000, you are right, it's not in the source code, i checked Java 1.8.0_241. But it's in the online java documentation, i checked from Java 13 all the way to 8, the Object() constructor is defined.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Super constructors are run before sub/base constructors. In your example Object's constructor has already been run when `new Throwable().printStackTrace()` is executed.

A more explicit version of your code:

```
public ConTest()
{
    super();
    new Throwable().printStackTrace(); // you will not see super() (Object.<init>) in this stack trace.
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You do not see it in the stack trace, because it was already called. The exception is thrown in your code.

Your code is equivalent to writing:

```
public ConTest() {
  super(); // this will call the Object constructor
  new Throwable().printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You do not see it in the stack trace because the constructor of the super class is called before your `new Throwable().printStackTace()` call. What the compiler actually creates is following .

```
public ConTest()
{
    super();   // This is the call to the base class constructor
    new Throwable().printStackTrace();   // already back from the base class constructor
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**Yes,Object class have a default constructor as the doc says.**

As you know insted of doing that you can check it by using javap -c ConTest in command prompt
you can see it's calling the object class default constructor() in below's code's **Line No:1**

```
C:\stackdemo>javap -c ConTest
Compiled from "ConTest.java"
public class ConTest extends java.lang.Object{
public ConTest();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   new     #2; //class java/lang/Throwable
   7:   dup
   8:   invokespecial   #3; //Method java/lang/Throwable."<init>":()V
   11:  invokevirtual   #4; //Method java/lang/Throwable.printStackTrace:()V
   14:  return

public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
   0:   new     #5; //class ConTest
   3:   dup
   4:   invokespecial   #6; //Method "<init>":()V
   7:   astore_1
   8:   return

}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

As Suggested above super() is the first call in the constructor and for   method More Information [here](http://www.artima.com/designtechniques/initializationP.html)

> When you compile a class, the Java compiler creates an instance initialization method for each constructor you declare in the source code of the class. Although the constructor is not a method, the instance initialization method is. It has a name, `<init>`, a return type, void, and a set of parameters that match the parameters of the constructor from which it was generated